# Pivot Header separate from Pivot Header location

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

I'm creating a Pivot control. Everything is okay. What I want is to place the pivot item in another Grid Row than the header.

This is what I have so far:

```
<Pivot Grid.Row="1" >
            <PivotItem>
                <PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" Margin="200,0,0,0">Photos</TextBlock>
                </PivotItem.Header>
                <assetsv:InnerView/>
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem>
                <PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" >Files</TextBlock>
                </PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock>Test 1</TextBlock>
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem >
                <PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" >Database</TextBlock>
                </PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock>Test 2</TextBlock>
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
```

I want to put The PivotItem.Header in `Grid.Row=0`, while the contents (either another view or a TextBlock) are contained in `Grid.Row=1`

Comment: May I know why you want to put the header and content in two grid rows? If you look at the [Pivot styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt299144.aspx), you will find they have be putted in two rows of the `Grid` named "PivotLayoutElement". Headers are in `ContentControl` named "HeaderClipper" and contents are in `ItemsPresenter` named "PivotItemPresenter".